# Google Map Does not appear in Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I want to show google maps in modal popup, but it doesn't seem to be appeared. Need Help.

Here is the HTML -

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 450px; background-color: grey;padding:0;margin:0"></div>
```

JS -

```
function initialize() {
    var myloc = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myloc,
        scrollwheel: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
    var contentString = '<div id="content" style="dir:rtl; text-align:right;">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><h1>title here</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p>description here</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 250
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here is the Popup preview image - 
  [Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tNwt.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `resize` on modal shown to refresh your map:

```
$('modal-id').on('shown.bs.modal', function () 
{
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @zakaria.. It worked.. But on 1st click its not working. when I click 2nd time on  button then it works. Could u help with this. Where I am doing mistake ??

Comment: @sajalsuraj make sure that the map is initialized before first click, sound like the first click init the map and second refresh it.

Comment: Thanks @JoaquínO for your intervention here, you're right he should define the map in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

I have added this for a static map load which is in the modal popup.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function()
{
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```